# Show that $\exists a,b$ such that $f'(a) = 1$ and $f'(b) = -1$

Tags: calculus

> Let $f(x) = x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}$ when $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$. Show that in every open interval about zero there are $a,b \in I$ such that $f'(a) = 1$ and $f'(b) = -1$.

**Attempt**

We have that $f'(x) = 2x\sin \frac{1}{x}-\cos \frac{1}{x}$. Now consider the interval $(a,b)$ such that $a < 0 < b$. We must show that either $f'(a) = -1$ or $f'(a) = 1$ and similarly for $f'(b)$. Obviously solving $2x\sin \frac{1}{a}-\cos \frac{1}{a} =  \pm 1$ is not going to be easy so I am wondering if there is a better way to approach this.

Comment: Actually, it is going to be easy -- try $1/2\pi n$ for any $n$.

Comment: Umm... don't use the same letters ($a$ and $b$) to designate both an arbitrary open interval around zero AND the (different!) $a$ and $b$ requested in the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $x$ of the form $\dfrac 1 {2 n \pi}$ for $n \to \infty$ - this solves half the problem. Can you solve the other half?

Comment: I think you mean $\frac{1}{2n}\pi$?

Comment: No, I mean what I wrote. What is $\frac 1 x$ then?

Comment: It is $2\pi n$.